# Compiz crash in virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, compiz, crash, opengl

I had fully working 64bit Ubuntu 14.04 under VirtualBox 4.3.20. I then updated ubuntu and virtualbox and now I can login but the Unity will not display because compiz crashes with segmentation fault - I have only background without any UI. It seems to be something related to opengl.

Starting Unity from terminal:

> stop: Unknown job: unity-panel-service
>   compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
>   compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core
>   start: Unknown job: unity-panel-service
>   compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ccp
>   compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ccp
>   compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: composite
>   compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: composite
>   compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: opengl
>   compiz (core) - Info: Unity is not supported by your hardware. Enabling software rendering instead (slow).
>   compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: opengl
>   No available targets are compatible with this -march, see -version for the available targets.
>
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

It seems to be something corrupted in my installation because Ubuntu 14.04 live CD booted from the same virtualbox works without any problems.

Comment: I already reinstalled guest additions, but it didn't solve segfault. I also have dkms installed.

Comment: I installed gnome flashback and compiz version also does not work. It seems to be something very odd in the compiz. The metacity works. Btw on my second computer it also reports "not supported" but compiz works normally.

Comment: I found the reason! In past I have added ppa for intel graphics drivers as I run the Ubuntu sometimes in native mode. Unfortunately the source included newer mesa packages, which caused the crash. After removing the intel source and manualy downgraded the mesa packages the compiz is working again. I cost me 2 days :-(

Answer (score 1):

Removing the intel driver PPA and force downgrading all mesa packages using standard repositories fixes the compiz crash.

The problem is in the latest MESA 10.3 drivers that came with last update of the intel graphic drivers through PPA. I installed Ubuntu to run both natively and inside VirtualBox. The MESA drivers from intel work in native mode but cause crash in swrast_dri.so within compiz.